# ActiveX control doesn't install from CAB file when http response has some particular Content-Type headers

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, activex, cab

When I open the web page, the web browser downloads the activeX control from the server.
It is interesting to see that when a http response doesn't have Content-Type header at all, the activeX control is installing fine.
However if we have `Content-Type = text/plain` or `Content-Type = application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed` the installation of the activeX fails.

1) What Content-Types should I try to succsessfully install the activeX  ?

2) Maybe there is some web browser (IE ofcourse) settings to resolve this issue? I mean to not block the activeX installation when the Content-Type isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with "application/zip" content type